# Curioso caso de "porque" en una pregunta: "¿*Porque* soy tu hermano?"

Tags: gramática

Me he topado con este diálogo:

> -¿Sabes por qué eres tan importante para mí?
>
> -¿**Porque** soy tu hermano?
>
> -Exacto

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Según la [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que) **porque** no puede usarse en una pregunta debería usarse **por qué**. El problema radica en que, de poner **por qué** (¿Por qué soy tu hermano?) cambiaría el sentido de la pregunta, puesto que pasaría a preguntar el porqué de ser hermanos, en lugar del porqué de ser tan importante.

¿Está bien formulada la pregunta?

Comment: Observa que la respuesta a esa pregunta no sería «Porque tal o cual cosa», sino «sí» o «no». No veo que ese enlace de la RAE diga que «porque» no puede usarse en una pregunta. En cualquier caso, añado un enlace que te podría interesar: http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/porque/porqu%C3%A9/por_que/por_qu%C3%A9 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El uso de "porque" en esa pregunta es correcto puesto que es una pregunta que **responde** a otra. La respuesta, por cierto, es dubitativa: de allí el uso del interrogativo.

También podríamos decir:

-¿Sabes por qué eres tan importante para mí?

-¿Acaso (soy importante para ti) **porque** soy tu hermano? ¿O tal vez (soy importante para ti) **porque** soy tu confidente? ¿O quizás (soy importante para ti) **porque** soy el único que tolera tus caprichos?

Las tres preguntas precedentes en realidad esconden **posibles respuestas** a la pregunta del interlocutor.